# How do I position multiple SVG files on top of each other in a way that is persistent across platforms in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, svg, expo

I am developing an app that includes a customizable avatar system in Expo / React Native. I have used SVGR to convert the avatar face parts into Components, and am positioning them on top of each other to form a face (expressions being changed by swapping part components, rotation, size, etc.) I can make the face look right on web, but as soon as I open it in iOS or android (be that my device or the sim), the height spacing is incorrect. Since this is an avatar, I do need the positioning to be exact between platforms.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import Head5 from './AvatarParts/Head';
import { Component } from 'react';
import Nose1 from './AvatarParts/Nose';
import Eye2 from './AvatarParts/Eye';
import Mouth1 from './AvatarParts/Mouth';
import Ear1 from './AvatarParts/Ear';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import Hair1 from './AvatarParts/Hair';
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

const sizeM = 3;

const NoseC = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(25 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(50 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const EyeL = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(15 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const EyeR = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(35 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const HeadC = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(100 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(100 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(0 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(0 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const MouthC = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(20 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(65 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const EarC = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(60 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(35 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const HairC = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(85 * sizeM)}px;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(85 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-left: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(7 * sizeM)}px;
  margin-top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(-20 * sizeM)}px;
`;
const AvatarC = styled.View`
  top: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(80)}px;
  position: absolute;
  width: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(100)}px;
  height: ${PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(100)}px;
`;
class Avatar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <AvatarC>
        <HeadC>
          <Head5 />
        </HeadC>
        <HairC>
          <Hair1 />
        </HairC>
        <NoseC>
          <Nose1 />
        </NoseC>
        <EyeL>
          <Eye2 />
        </EyeL>
        <EyeR>
          <Eye2 />
        </EyeR>
        <MouthC>
          <Mouth1 />
        </MouthC>
        <EarC>
          <Ear1 />
        </EarC>
      </AvatarC>
    );
  }
}

export default Avatar;
```

I appreciate your help! Here are the results of the above on the three platforms platforms
[iOS & android render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTAAo.png)
[Web render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGzVT.png)